How to open double glazed window with no handle and broken hardware
Bought a house and found that the bathroom window is missing the handle so can't be opened, and appears to have either broken internal hardware or is missing something so that a new handle can't be fitted. If I can manage to open the window hopefully I'll be able to replace the internal mechanism and fit a new handle? I'm thinking I should be able to jam something in the hole and get it to engage, but so far my attempts with screwdrivers, pliers, etc. haven't worked. What would you use?


a zoom out of the window might help.  any idea on brand.  are you other windows similar - are they tilt and turn or just casement?

it looks rusted, so hard to move, use flash light to see the type of the center hole, then use fitting tool

Two ideas:

If you have identical windows elsewhere, you could try borrowing the handle off one of those. Chose wisely though: there's a fair chance that you'll have little plastic covers over the fixing screws which won't come off and go back on again nicely.

If you're really lucky the spindle from a common doorknob would fit, turned with a spanner.  More realistically you'd have to file it down.


Replacement handles are quite common in a wide range of designs (example shop).  You might just be able to buy one and fit (some of) it without opening the window first.  Again, if you've got identical ones that would help.
Note: These windows in the UK almost always have a latch or even a key-operated lock, however all of that is likely to be in the bit that's missing. I think the internal hardware is all present, but dislodged and damaged.  It looks rather like attempts have been made to brute force it already
My approach would be to either borrow the handle off a matching window, or measure up on that window checking the dimensions against these holes as much as possible. Then  try to order a replacement, and start the work with it in hand.  That minimises the chance of getting it open then not being able to secure/seal it again.

It looks like the center hole gives access to a cam with a square opening. That is undoubtedly what the handle operated. If you can find a replacement lever with the right size and length square shaft, it ought to work, even if the mounting holes don't line up with the holes from the previous handle. You can try it first before driving the screws, of course, to confirm that you do have the right size and that there is nothing else wrong with the mechanism.

Well, the center hole used to, anyway!  Looks like the "square" no longer is.

If it is too warm to fit a handle to, the only answer is going to be to find some way to force it open, dismount it, and replace it. The replacement will probably come with a handle. The best guess I have for forcing it involves trying to jam a tool into that opening, possibly a screwdriver blade, so you can rotate it. But past attempts may be why that hole is so worn...

I wonder if that's what made the gouge marks to the left of the holes...

Worn, not warm. I have got to stop trusting dictation.
